# Contact form that doesn't refresh page on submit while using Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, wordpress

I have setup the following code to make a contact form that doesn't refresh the page when submitted.

**HTML:**

```
<form method="POST" id="contact-form">
  <div class="contact-element flex-row">
    <input class="" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" id="name" Required>
    <input class="" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" id="email" Required>
  </div>
  <input class="" type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" id="subject" Required>
  <textarea type="text" name="message" rows="5" placeholder="Message" id="message" Required></textarea>
  <input class="contact-submit" id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="form-action">
</form>
```

**JavaScript/AJAX request:**

```
$("#contact-form").submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var $form = $( this ),
      url = "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/library/contact-form.php";
  var posting = $.post( url, {
    name: $('#name').val(),
    email: $('#email').val(),
    subject: $('#subject').val(),
    message: $('#message').val(),
  });
  posting.done(function( data ) {
    alert('success');
  });
});
```

**PHP:**

```
// Set $to as the email you want to send the test to.
$to = "my@email.com";

// Email subject and body text.
$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$subject = $_POST["subject"];
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($_POST['email']) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$message = $_POST["message"];

// send test message using wp_mail function.
if(isset(($_POST['name']), ($_POST['email']), ($_POST['message']), ($_POST["subject"]))) {
  $sent_message = wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
} else {

};

//display message based on the result.
if ( $sent_message ) {
    // The message was sent.
    echo 'The test message was sent. Check your email inbox.';
} else {
    // The message was not sent.
    echo 'The message was not sent!';
}
```

The code works when I run it on my local website, It returns the success alert.
The PHP code also succeeds in sending the contact form information to my email address.

I get a 'the server responded with a status of 500 (internal error)' when I run it on my web server.

I think I must have overlooked something stupid here but I can't see it and hoping someone else can see it and help me out?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i do my ajax submission for a form. It's contains WordPress security measures, you can learn them from google in detail but small description will be provided by me.

### HTML

```
<form method="POST" id="contact-form">
    <div class="contact-element flex-row">
        <input class="" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" id="name" Required>
        <input class="" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" id="email" Required>
    </div>
    <input class="" type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" id="subject" Required>
    <textarea type="text" name="message" rows="5" placeholder="Message" id="message" Required></textarea>
    <input class="contact-submit" id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="contact_form" id="cf_action" url="<?= admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>">
    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'contact_form', 'contact_form_wpnonce' ); ?>
</form>
```

### Javascript

```
jQuery(function($){
    $("#contact-form").submit(function(e){
        var url = $('#cf_action').attr('url');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: $("#contact-form").serialize(),
            success: function(data) { 
                alert(data.data);
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
    });
});
```

### Function

```
add_action('wp_ajax_contact_form', 'contact_form_function');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_contact_form', 'contact_form_function'); 
function contact_form_function()
{   
    if ( !isset($_POST['xyz_contact_email_meta_box_nonce']) && !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['xyz_contact_email_meta_box_nonce'], 'xyz_save_contact_email_data')) {
        # code...
        return;
    }
    $user_name  = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['name'] );
    $user_email = sanitize_email( $_POST['email'] );
    $user_subject = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['subject'] );
    $user_message = sanitize_textarea_field( $_POST['message'] );
    $to = 'xyz@gmail.com';
    $subject = $user_subject;
    $body = 'Hi you recived a message from '.$user_name.'('.$user_email.'),<p>'.$user_message.'</p>';
    $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
    $status = wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers );
    if($status){
        wp_send_json_success('sent successful');
    }else{
        wp_send_json_error('something went wrong');
    }
}
```

### Description

okay let me guide through WordPress a bit.
WordPress have already inbuilt functionality to handle ajax-request from it's theme's functions.php, you have to copy and paste html code where you want form to show, js code in footer and  function code in functions.php

Here are some tips:-

1. wp_nonce_field = it's used for security purpose and prevent hackers to use form for different purpose.
2. Sanitize data to make sure you are not receiving any malicious code from your posted data, you can use esc_attr(it will convert any tags and script into html) too.
3. It's a good habit to send data back with WordPress default function wp_send_json_success & wp_send_json_error.

(Forgive me if you feel hard to understand since it's my first answer on stackoverflow)
Cheers!!

Comment: This sorted my problem! I knew it was something related to the Wordpress but couldn't seem to work out where. I changed my code around a bit and added what you said above and it's all working now. Thanks alot!

Comment: Glad to help you out 